# Where is the variable vm defined?

Tags: vuejs2, jhipster

I've been going through the code generated by JHipster using clientFramework vue

The *entity*-update.component.ts files each include the funtion `beforeRouteEnter`,
in the following example the entity type is `AppUser`

My question is where is the variable `vm` defined ?
I also don't see a definition for `vm` in the *main.ts* file which creates the Vue object as:

**main.ts**

```js
/* tslint:disable */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  router,
  provide: { ...
```

**app-user-update.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Vue, Inject } from 'vue-property-decorator';

import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

import AlertService from '@/shared/alert/alert.service';

import PersonService from '@/entities/iqcore/person/person.service';
import { IPerson } from '@/shared/model/iqcore/person.model';

import PartyService from '@/entities/iqcore/party/party.service';
import { IParty } from '@/shared/model/iqcore/party.model';

import { IAppUser, AppUser } from '@/shared/model/iqcore/app-user.model';
import AppUserService from './app-user.service';

const validations: any = {
  appUser: {
    userLogin: {
      required,
    },
  },
};

@Component({
  validations,
})
export default class AppUserUpdate extends Vue {
  @Inject('appUserService') private appUserService: () => AppUserService;
  @Inject('alertService') private alertService: () => AlertService;

  public appUser: IAppUser = new AppUser();

  @Inject('personService') private personService: () => PersonService;

  public people: IPerson[] = [];

  @Inject('partyService') private partyService: () => PartyService;

  public parties: IParty[] = [];
  public isSaving = false;
  public currentLanguage = '';

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      if (to.params.appUserId) {
        vm.retrieveAppUser(to.params.appUserId);
      }
      vm.initRelationships();
    });
  }

  created(): void {
    this.currentLanguage = this.$store.getters.currentLanguage;
    this.$store.watch(
      () => this.$store.getters.currentLanguage,
      () => {
        this.currentLanguage = this.$store.getters.currentLanguage;
      }
    );
  }

  public save(): void {
    this.isSaving = true;
    if (this.appUser.id) {
      this.appUserService()
        .update(this.appUser)
        .then(param => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.$router.go(-1);
          const message = this.$t('iqcoreApp.iqcoreAppUser.updated', { param: param.id });
          return this.$root.$bvToast.toast(message.toString(), {
            toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
            title: 'Info',
            variant: 'info',
            solid: true,
            autoHideDelay: 5000,
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.alertService().showHttpError(this, error.response);
        });
    } else {
      this.appUserService()
        .create(this.appUser)
        .then(param => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.$router.go(-1);
          const message = this.$t('iqcoreApp.iqcoreAppUser.created', { param: param.id });
          this.$root.$bvToast.toast(message.toString(), {
            toaster: 'b-toaster-top-center',
            title: 'Success',
            variant: 'success',
            solid: true,
            autoHideDelay: 5000,
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.alertService().showHttpError(this, error.response);
        });
    }
  }

  public retrieveAppUser(appUserId): void {
    this.appUserService()
      .find(appUserId)
      .then(res => {
        this.appUser = res;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.alertService().showHttpError(this, error.response);
      });
  }

  public previousState(): void {
    this.$router.go(-1);
  }

  public initRelationships(): void {
    this.personService()
      .retrieve()
      .then(res => {
        this.people = res.data;
      });
    this.partyService()
      .retrieve()
      .then(res => {
        this.parties = res.data;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vm` is your component instance. It's "injected" by the router component to access e.g. functions inside the component that should be rendered.

See also https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards for details.